# Transfer data from child to parent MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

Help me please to find a solution. I want to pass data from child MFC dialog EditBox to parent dialog CString variable after close the child dialog. I open the child dialog from parent MFC Property page this way:

```
    void ParentDialog::OnButtonClicked()
{

    ChildDialog child = new ChildDialog(this);       
    child->DoModal();
    CString parentdata = child->m_data;// m_data holds data from EditBox


}
```

But anytime i close the child dialog, m_data is not available to parent. Help me please to pass data that i entered in child EditBox to parent CString variable. Thank you very much.

Comment: *"m_data is not available to parent"* - What does that mean? You get a compiler error, because the class member does not exist or is not accessible? You get a runtime error? You don't get any error at all, but do no receive the expected result either?

Comment: I found a solution. My mistake was in the way i tried to add the m_data to the std::map in parent dialog. I called the addtomap function from the child dialog before it was closed and finally got the bad pointer. Sorry for that question. It closed. Thank you very much for your time and help...

Comment: Many decide to make their dialogue variables **private** and add public **methods** to get/set the value before/after the dialogue has been displayed.